# Implementing Google AdMob to iOS app

Tags: objective-c

As shown in the picture I'm having issues implementing Google AdMob into my app. Yes I am new to this and I figured using this site would be a good to learn. Since you guy's answer quickly.

http://i601.photobucket.com/albums/tt93/masterhomieg/Screenshots/ScreenShot2014-05-13at63814PM_zps64ec9cb6.png

Comment: String values are like this: `@"some string"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put `@""` around the string like this:

```
self.adBanner.adUnitID= @"ca-app-pub-689930294...";
```

Comment: Thanks that worked sorry I'm a noob lol! At least I'm not afraid to admit it.